# How to stop a program based on user's input in C

Tags: c

I'm just starting to learn C and I'm having problem with stopping my program based on what the user inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
int a;
int b;
char c[5];
printf("Enter the two values you like to compare, type stop to end.\n");
while (c != "stop")
{
    scanf_s(" %d %d %s", &a, &b, &c);
    if (!(a^b))
    {
        printf("both are equal\n");
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("both are not equal\n");
        getchar();
    }
}
printf("Thanks for playing.");
getchar();
return 0;   
}
```

The problem that I'm having is having to put in another variable, c, in my scanf_s. How would I do it so that the user does not have to put in another word after the 2 numbers? Also how can I check if the user only input "stop" so that it will stop the program? Btw the way I have it right now also does not stop the program when I do "10 10 stop". Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `getch();` funtion before `return 0;` remember you include conio.h `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: You compare string using [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) in C, not `==` or `!=`.

Comment: Note: Recommend to _always_ check the result of `scanf()` and family.

Answer (score 3):

1. remove & for c in scanf_s(" %d %d %s", &a, &b, &c);
2. use strcmp to compare strings.
3. if you need to ignore case while comparing use strcasecmp (for UNIX based systems) and stricmp (for windows).
4. Use do-while instead of while if you need to run the loop at least once.

Full Working Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int a;
  int b;
  char c[5] = {'\0'};

  do {
    printf("Enter the two values you like to compare, type stop to end.\n");
    scanf("%d%d%s", &a, &b, c);
    if (!(a^b))
      {
    printf("both are equal\n");
    getchar();
      }
    else
      {
    printf("both are not equal\n");
    getchar();
      }
  }
  while (strcmp(c,"stop"));
  printf("Thanks for playing.");
  getchar();
  return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`while (c != "stop")`

You cannot compare `strings` in C like that, use `memcmp()` or `strncmp()` library functions available in `string.h`. Read about them to know how they can be implemented as condition in `while` loop.

Also, to get string input, use
`scanf_s(" %d %d %s", &a, &b, c);  // Remove that litle '&' before 'c'.`

NOTE: The function `scanf_s` returns the number of inputs scanned correctly, you should check that before proceeding with input values.

To get the user to stop without explicitly entering "stop", many ways are there:

1) Use `do-while` loop and keep asking user if he wants to play more.
2) Use negative numbers input (say `-1`) to quit.

Answer (score 1):

Use line below to make sure your 'c' scan your string entered.

> scanf(" %d %d %s", &a, &b, c);

Edit:
Consider replacing your while with line below to make sure you stop works. Include "string.h"

> ```
> while (strcmp(c,"stop"))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed version... I have add the comments in the code for understanding...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[5] = {'\0'};
    printf("Enter the two values you like to compare, type stop to end.\n");
    while (strcmp(c,"stop"))
    {
        scanf("%d%d%s", &a, &b, c);
        if (!(a^b))
        {
            printf("both are equal\n");
            getchar();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("both are not equal\n");
            getchar();
        }
    }
    printf("Thanks for playing.");
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However my program still doesn't stop when I put in something like "10 10 stop" or "stop".

Comment: Dont include any space in scanf... that is, you have to use it like this scanf("%d%d%s",&a,&b,c);, there should not be space in "%d%d%s"

Comment: It says error C4996 when I try to use scanf instead of scanf_s.

Comment: @user3128376 : You can try using `fgets` separately for scanning the string.

Comment: Maybe I should have mention this earlier but I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I was reading that I need to use scanf_s instead of scanf. My codes are completely like yours except for the scanf part. However, the program is still not stopping for me.

Comment: @user3128376: try to copy the code, paste in VS2013 and check

Comment: @user3128376 : There is something called `debugging the code`, try that. **1)** Print the value of `c`; **2)** Check return value of `scanf` (or `scanf_s`). **3)** Try assigning "stop" directly to `c` while initialization.

Comment: @Nishith Jain M R Using `scanf(" %d %d %s",&a,&b,c)` or `scanf("%d%d%s",&a,&b,c)` will provide the same functionality.  `%d` and `%s` both consume leading whitespace just like `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using `&c` instead of just `c` in `scanf_s`. Replace that and it should work. Also, `c` is a `string`, so, you have to use `strcmp` instead of `!=`.

An easier way to write this code would be::

```
int main()
{
int a;
int b;
char c;
do
{
    printf("Would you like to play?\nPress 'Y' for 'Yes' or 'N' for 'No'\n");
    scanf( "%c", &c ) ;
    /*scanf_s( "%c", &c, 1 ) ; */
    if( c != 'Y' && c != 'y' )
        break ;

    printf("Enter the two values you like to compare\n" ) ;
    scanf(" %d %d", &a, &b);
    if (!(a^b))
    {
        printf("both are equal\n");
        getchar();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("both are not equal\n");
        getchar();
    }
}while(1) ;
printf("Thanks for playing.");
getchar();
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @0xF1 : Exactly. How I did not think about that?

Comment: I tried it this way however when I put N or n, it just asks me to enter the values again and won't quit.

Comment: @user3128376: Fixed. "Replaced || with &&"

Comment: I think it should be "if (c == 'N' || c == 'n')"
And it won't quit when I put "n" or "N"

Comment: Y for sure denotes that the user wants to play. So, its always better to check the user consent against his willingness to play. If he presses any other key other than "y", he should be able to exit. Thats' why I am checking for "!= Y".

Comment: I see. But it automatically quits when I put in "y", "Y", "n" or "N".

Comment: Please check the current code I have posted. I have tested it and it works good for me.

Comment: I did. The only difference is that I had to change scanf to scanf_s otherwise my visual studio 2013 won't let me compile.

Comment: scanf_s expects the buffer size, so just replace with "scanf_s( "%c", &c, 1 ) ;"

Answer (score 1):

First, lets correct your program:
`&c` (third argument to scanf_s) is incorrect. It should be `c` (because it is already a pointer). According to docs, `scanf_s` [requires sizes to be specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) for all `%s` format strings; therefore, the way you are doing things now, you should have written `scanf_s(" %d %d %4s", &a, &b, c);`

The program would be much easier to use if you changed your logic to "enter a blank line to exit". You can test this looking at the return value of `scanf_s`, which will be the number of format strings correctly read from the input.

If you *need* to ask for strings, then allow either, and look at whatever the user wrote to see whether it was number or string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main()  {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[32];
    printf("Enter the two values to compare, or type stop to end.\n");
    while (fgets(c, 31, stdin) != NULL && strncmp("stop\n", c)) != 0) {

        // user did not request to exit and wrote something; maybe 2 numbers
        if (sscanf(c, "%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) {
            // but he did not write two numbers. Complain and repeat.
            printf("please write two numbers to compare, or type stop to end.\n");
            continue; 
        }

        if (a == b) {
            printf("both are equal\n");
        } else  {
            printf("both are not equal\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Thanks for playing.\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

`fgets` reads whole lines, and you can then try to parse them using `sscanf`. This has the advantage over common `scanf` that you can try to parse the same line in different ways, depending on what you find in it. Generally, you do *not* want to fill your code with `getchar()`. If you are debugging, your debugger will stop for you. If you are not debugging, you will want to test or use your program with [input redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29%E2%80%8E), and `getchar()` is simply not needed.

Comment: +1 for `fgets()` and `sscanf()` and checking results.  BTW: `fgets(c, 32, stdin)` is OK - no need for 32-1.  `fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin)` is even better.  Note: given that an `int` _could_ be 64-bits these days, maybe a larger `c[2*21+2]`.